# SQL Query Summary

Tags: mysql, sql

i would create a particular sql string.

I have this tables :

```
cities
-----------
city varchar not null  primary key
etc


weeks
-----------
week varchar not null  primary key


Insert_data
-----------
id int not null  primary key
cityID varchar
week varchar
value1 int
etc
```

I would to bind asp.net gridview with this table structure:

```
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| city| week1 | week2 | week3 |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
|   1 | (y/n) | (y/n) | (y/n) |
|   2 | (y/n) | (y/n) | (y/n) |
|   3 | (y/n) | (y/n) | (y/n) |
|   4 | (y/n) | (y/n) | (y/n) |
|   5 | (y/n) | (y/n) | (y/n) |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
```

if there are records related to that week in insert_data the value will be Y.

It's possible to create a query string for this?

Comment: Which database and version are you using?

Comment: I'm using mysql 5 with asp.net

Comment: The database matters. A lot. ASP.NET does not matter. At all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>As always, when you need to create columns from rows with a "group by argument" (city), you can use the PIVOT operator.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx</del>

Above only applies to MS-SQL, doesn't apply to MySQL.

Or you can do it the old-fashioned way

```
SELECT 
     cities.city
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN weeks.week = 1 THEN Insert_data.value1 ELSE 0 END) AS week1
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN weeks.week = 2 THEN Insert_data.value1 ELSE 0 END) AS week2
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN weeks.week = 3 THEN Insert_data.value1 ELSE 0 END) AS week3
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN weeks.week = 4 THEN Insert_data.value1 ELSE 0 END) AS week4
     -- ,etc. for each week (select distinct week from insert_data order by week)
FROM Insert_data
left join cities
    cities.city= Insert_data.cityID 
left join weeks
    on weeks.week = Insert_data.week

group by cities.city
```

Either way, you need to dynamically hardcode the weeks in your SQL string.

You would now need an additional condition for y and n, and then you can concat the values.

```
      ,'(' + CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN weeks.week = 1 AND value1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as varchar(10))
+ '/'
CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN weeks.week = 1 AND value1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as varchar(10))
+ ')'
AS week1
```

or if it's just y or no, then

```
      ,
      CASE 
          WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN weeks.week = 1 THEN Insert_data.value1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 
               THEN 'y'
          ELSE 'n'
    END AS week1
```